# Why semi-colon is not required after use database statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Kindly help me to understand the reason to put `delimiter (;)` after every MySQL statement. Can we change default delimiter to some other character(like `|` ). And why it is not required to put `;` after `USE database` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You change the delimiter with the `delimiter` statement. eg

`delimiter //`, then all your statements will need to be terminated with a `//`

this is necessary when defining stored procedures or triggers that require compound statements.

You can (obviously) change it back to a semi-colon with `delimiter ;`

`use` doesn't require a delimiter (in the command line client) because it's a cli command, not an sql command. (at least, [according to this bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54829))